# Using Akka Actors with Play Framework in async processes

Tags: asynchronous, playframework, akka

I'm \using Play Framework in creating web-services but I'm new in Akka.

I've already built a process in Play which generates some files depending on SQL query results. User sends request to the services and waiting about 10 minutes 
for the process to complete.
I want to convert this process to be totally asynchronous and work like a background process on demand. When user sends a request he get's a response with message that request received, process started, and there is a link in response to get process status.

Using the link user can send a status request and receive current status, for example: "Queued", "In progress: 10%", "Complete", "Failed. Error message: Not connected to database".

How I can develop this process using Akka?
Could you post a quick source code example?

Comment: The answer depends on a number of factors. Does your background process already store its progress somewhere? Does the background job need to be resilient & monitored, or is it OK if it fails occasionally? From the browser, do you want to check status via a single chunked request, periodic AJAX requests, or a pub/sub system with WebSockets? See also: http://www.jamesward.com/2015/06/02/redirecting-and-chunking-around-herokus-30-second-request-timeout

Comment: I have similar requirement,  my web application (Spring based) communicate to another simple java application using ActiveMQ.  This simple java application do the asynchronous job for me and send the status to the user on completion of task. 
Could anyone help me to figure out whether I can replace this ActiveMQ consumer (core java application) with Akka to perform all the jobs in background asynchronously?